# Install tomcat 8

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat8

I have a problem with tomcat, I can not install version 8, when I select version 7 everything goes well but when I choose version 8 it leaves me not complete the configuration:

[image]

I use eclipse mars, and java 8

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Close Eclipse

2.Just delete following two files from  **workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings**

- **org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs**
- **org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs**

3.Restart eclipse

Comment: It works ! Thank you. Do you have any idea why this happens ?